# Does the underlying platform affect the speedof any web site or web application?

Tags: java, php, .net, programming-languages

I have sometimes seen that some applications that are built in php are comparatively faster than those that are developed in .net or java. I have seen some other projects also behaving same. Generally application built in .net are comparatively slower. Best example I have seen is facebook. It works well even if there is low connection or low bandwitdh but at that time other sites dont work. Does the underlying technology really matter??

Comment: django, symphony=framework
PHP, C# = programming laguage

do not confuse them. Frameworks simply simplify creating/updating webpages, languages can be used to develop webpages, desktop applications, mobile applications, plugins, other programming languages, frameworks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a comparable level of skill for the people developing / operating the site, comparable infrastructure, and enough development admin time to optimize the system to the abilities of those people, then yes, it makes a lot of difference.

However, IME, the biggest differentiator between languages is not what their intrinsic perfromance, but:

1. the level and availability of skilled developers / admins
2. the amount of effort required to achieve a given end result

The lower barriers of entry to PHP programming compared with Java, means it is a lot easier to find a competent software engineer proficient in Java compared with one proficient in PHP, *despite* PHP skills being much more widely asserted.

OTOH, if you look at software metrics, PHP almost always trounces Java in terms of LOC/productivity. And unless you are Google or Facebook, salaries are a much greater cost than hardware - if it's slow, buy more infrastructure.

Don't get me started on .net

Answer (score 1):

Hardly, its the type and quality of application that really matters.

What you could do is just create a test page, one that for example only makes one database call and display its output, in each of your languages. You'll notice they are fairly equal, the user wont notice any difference.

It all depends on the application, large complicated applications are often slower. There are many ways to optimize, in all the languages available.

Perhaps some languages and frameworks do tend to 'feel' slower, for example ASP.net is considered a bit bloated, and could feel slower. However a competent developer working on an ASP.net site will make it more performant then a less competent PHP developer.

Comment: Hear, hear. In my experience, slow applications (be it web or otherwise) usually have some serious architectural and engineering flaws. Of course the framework or language used also has impact on performance, but the implementation on top of these frameworks is magnitudes more important.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it matters. It all comes down on how fast and efficient your request can be processed.

Once the processing is done, sending back the website content will be dependent on your Internet connection.

However, the processing on the server side depends on the framework. If the framework is poorly implemented, then your website will respond slower.

Holla if you need more details.